# understanding the output of echo followed by some exlamation marks

Tags: bash, echo

I was playing with `echo $$` a while back. Well that displays that pid of the shell. But then I did `echo !` which promptly displayed !. Then `echo !!` produced

```
echo echo !
echo !
```

`$echo !!!` gave

```
echo echo echo !!
echo echo !!
```

I couldn't understand the outputs. As far as I know, `echo !!` gives the last command that was executed on shell. But the outputs that I get here are weird for me to understand. I use bash shell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [history event designator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Event-Designators) `!!` is replaced by the last command in your history. Bash first prints out the command how it will be executed, then executes it.

Example:

```
$ foo
foo: command not found
$ !!
foo                     # command to be executed
foo: command not found  # result of execution
```

In your case:

```
$ echo !
!
$ echo !!
echo echo !         # command to be executed
echo !              # result of execution
$ echo !!!
echo echo echo !!   # command to be executed
echo echo !!        # result of execution
```

Note that a command with an event designator is not inserted into history as typed. First the event designator gets expanded and then the command is entered into history. That is why in the third command (`echo !!!`), the event designator is not replaced by `echo !!` (the typed second command), but by `echo echo !` (the expanded second command).

Here is the last command again with the replaced part highlighted:

```
$ echo (!!)!
echo (echo echo !)! # command to be executed
echo echo !!        # result of execution
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `!!` that it is **substituted** by the **last command** in the shell, so the **first line** is the to **show the substitution** `echo echo !` and the **second** one is the **output** `echo !`